# can't find why loop don't go inside my condition in my java serrvlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WorldDBManager DB = new WorldDBManager();
    String choices = request.getParameter("selectchoice");
    List<WorlPopulationInfo> country = new ArrayList<>();

    country = DB.getResultAsArrayList("world", "select * from country");


    StringBuffer strB = new StringBuffer();


    for(int i=0;i<country.size();i++){
        if(country.get(i).countryName == choices){
            strB.append("<option selected='selected'>" + country.get(i).countryName+"</option>");
            System.out.println(choices + " pareil " + country.get(i).countryName);
        }else if(country.get(i).countryName != choices){
            strB.append("<option>" + country.get(i).countryName+"</option>");
            System.out.println(choices + " " + country.get(i).countryName);
        }
    }


    request.setAttribute("country", strB);




    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,  response);

}
```

i don't understand why he doesnt go to the first if condition  i know the value from variable choices exist inside my database by doing a System.println. i just don't understand why is ignoring my equality. If someone could explain me what im doing wrong. thank.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try -

```
if(country.get(i).countryName.equals(choices)){
```

You don't need `else If` there, only `else` would be sufficient

```
 if(country.get(i).countryName.equals(choices)){
            strB.append("<option selected='selected'>" + country.get(i).countryName+"</option>");
            System.out.println(choices + " pareil " + country.get(i).countryName);
        }else{
            strB.append("<option>" + country.get(i).countryName+"</option>");
            System.out.println(choices + " " + country.get(i).countryName);
        }
```

Comment: oh thx damn i forgot that one lol i feel stupid

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals() for string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can´t compare string with == (maybe in 1.7). You have to use

```
if(country.get(i).countryName.equals(choices)){}
```

Comment: yeah i complete forgot that one. I don't know what i was thinking and stuck there like 20-30mins